# Use ngx-translate with ng2-select in Angular 5 app

Tags: ngx-translate, angular-ngselect

I want to use ngx-translate for items in ng2-select. The only way I can think of is using the translate service and mutate the items' text in ts file prior to binding.

Is there a way to use pipe or directive as I want to make it consistent.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find any solution for this? I am trying the same thing

Comment: Hi @IosifPetre, thanks for the answer, I ended up creating my own dropdown component based on ngx-bootstrap.

Comment: ok, can you show your solution? your custom dropdown component may help others trying to do the same thing

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to create a pipe and use it on the items of the select:

```
<ng-select [items]="listOfTimeOfExecution | selectOptionsTranslate" ...
```

and pipe code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate/ng2-translate';
import { SelectOption } from 'app/shared/entities';

@Pipe({name: 'selectOptionsTranslate'})
export class SelectOptionsTranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(public translateService: TranslateService){}

    transform(items: Array<SelectOption>) : Array<SelectOption> {
        for(let item of items) {
            item.text = this.translateService.instant(item.text);
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: It also works for placeholder as long as you bind it [placeholder]=" 'my.translation' | translate" using the native ngx-translate pipe

Comment: usage of `translateService.instant` is not recommended, https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/516 as he mentioned "You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If you are not sure then you should use the `get` method instead."

Answer (score 3):

My solution is inspired by [Iosif's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48968369/10284117) for which I can't make it work properly becuz of the **async characteristics** of the translateService

Secondly, I also need to translate the options when user **changes language**.

So here's my solution (I wrote a pipe as well) for handling the above 2 issues:

**Dependencies:** 
Angular 6 
"@ng-select/ng-select": "2.5.1", 
"@ngx-translate/core": "^10.0.2",

**translate-options.pipe.ts** 
(Rmbr to import it to the declaration array of app.module.ts)

```
// ... Rmbr to import the libs ...

@Pipe({
  name: 'translateOptions',
})
export class TranslateOptionsPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }


  transform(items: any) {    
    const observable = Observable.create(observer => {
        this.translateService.get(items).subscribe(result => {            
            // result will be an object
            // e.g. { 'JOBS.UX': 'UX Designer', 'JOBS.DEVELOPER': 'Developer' }
            observer.next(result);
        });        

        this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe(event => {
            this.translateService.get(items).subscribe(result => {            
                observer.next(result);
            });
        })
    });

    return observable;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.translateService.onLangChange.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html** 
**items** in the code below will be an array of your translation keys, something like: 
['JOBS.DEVELOPER', 'JOBS.UX', 'JOBS.PM']

```
<ng-select
    [addTag]="true"
    [addTagText]="to.addTagText || 'Create item: '"
    [multiple]="to.multiple"
    [closeOnSelect]="!to.multiple"
    (change)="onAutoCompleteChange($event)"  
>
    <ng-option
        *ngFor="let item of items | translateOptions | async | keyvalue" 
        [value]="item.key"
    >
        {{ item.value }}
    </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: The TranslateService language change observer was super helpful! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The parent that use dropdown will pass an object typed as following to the dropdown component.

```
export interface IDropdownOptions {
  items: any[];
  itemType: 'action' | 'divider';
  itemLabel: (item: any) => string;

  itemClicked?: (item: any) => void; // overwriting default onChange function
  itemVisible?: (item: any) => boolean;
  itemSelectable?: (item: any) => boolean;

  selectedText: (() => string) | string;
  shortSelectedText?: (() => string) | string;
  // can define more for styling and custom purposes...
}
```

Then I have my dropdown component to implements ControlValueAccessor to be available in angular form

```
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';
import { get } from 'lodash';

@Component({
  selector: 'c-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  providers: [{ provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: forwardRef(() => DropdownComponent), multi: true }]
})
export class DropdownComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() options: IDropdownOptions;
  onChange: any = () => {};

  get itemLabel(): (item: any) => string {
    return !!get(this.options, 'itemLabel')
      ? this.options.itemLabel
      : () => '';
  }

  get itemClicked(): (item: any) => void {
    !!get(this.options, 'itemClicked')
      ? this.options.itemClicked
      : this.onChange;
  }

  // Getter functions for itemSelectable, itemVisible, etc.

  constructor() {}

  // Other inherited functions...

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

}
```

Inside template's for loop, you can use translate pipe with itemLabel(item).